# import xmltodict module into visual studio code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, xmltodict

I am having a little tough time importing the xmltodict module into my visual studio code. 
I setup the module in my windows using pip. it should be working on my visual studio as per the guidelines and relevant posts I found here. 
but for some reasons it isn't working in the visual studio. 
Please advise on how can I get the xmltodict module installed or imported on visual studio code

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that it wasn't installed in that virtual environment even though that was what I had done. Try:
venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip install xmltodict